# Maximum of two number in C using bitwise operators

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the maximum of two numbers without using if-else or any other comparison operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772780/find-the-maximum-of-two-numbers-without-using-if-else-or-any-other-comparison-ope)

isGreater:

```
if x > y  then return 1, else return 0
```

Example:

- isGreater(4,5) = 0
- isGreater(5,4) = 1

Legal operators: `! ~ & ^ | + << >>`

isGreater is the function..

I tried:

```
int isGreater(int x, int y) {
    return (y+(~x+1)) >> 31 & 1;
}
```

but not working.. :((
Let me know what else I can do?

Comment: What is with the endless stream of "how do I do X with some limited subset of the C operators?" type questions?

Comment: Step 1.  Please format your code using the `{}` button.  Step 2.  Please mark your homework with the [homework] tag.

Comment: @Oli, it's a common homework assignment, apparently.

Comment: @thkala: mostly - but `+` is binary and not bitwise...(unless it is a mistake).

Comment: @Oli: it looks like it's probably from a computer architecture class, where they're only allowed to use things that can be implemented with simple gates (and, or, not) or simple combinations of them (xor, adder, shifter).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: while not totally accurate, I think that using "bitwise" reflects the intent of the question better...

Comment: can you provide a counter example to why that code is not working? It makes sense... you basically do y - x and return 1 if and only if that is negative (meaning x > y). (barring any architecture differences)

Comment: The title says "Maximum of two numbers" whereas the question itself suggests that you just want to test for `x > y` - which is it ???

Comment: @Jonathan - + can also be a unary operator, which isn't _exactly_ bitwise but can easily be implemented in terms of bitwise operations :p

Comment: @Chris: yes; plus is a unary 'do nothing' operator (as well as a meaningful binary operator), which is why unary plus was not a part of pre-standard C.

Comment: This is a reasonable homework assignment **for a math class**, not for a programming class.

Answer (score 0):

given x, y

try x + -y
if < 0 then y is greater, if > 0 then x is greater.

-y = binary complement of y:

```
-y = (~(y-1))
<==>
-y = (~y)+1
```

From what I see, you do the binary complement with (~y +1)), which is the same.

Then bitshift >> 31 to get the MSB, and equal to 1.
Make sure to set parantheses, operator precedence !

```
 (y+-x) >> (31 & 1);
!=
 ((y+-x) >> 31) & 1;
```

Comment: @Paul apparently you didn't read his answer

Answer (score 0):

Too easy -- since you have `+` in the list of legal operators, you can trivially synthesize `-` (as others have noticed) and thus do a subtract and extract the sign.  Its much more interesting if you leave out `+` (as it isn't a bitwise operator anyways) and answer the question with just bitwise ops (`&` `|` `^` `~`) and shifts.

Of course, you could synthesize `+`/`-` from the bitwise ops and shifts, but there's actually an easier way.

Comment: That restriction does make it more interesting, though I can't +1 in good conscience as you're really asking a separate question.  The solution I have in mind requires 5 right-shifts, which I suspect is the minimum possible number.