# How to Find the Max Integer Value in a Stack without using max() or iterating over it?

Tags: java

I was asked in an interview the following question: if you have a Stack of Integers how would you find the max value of the Stack without using Collections.max and without iterating over the Stack and comparing elements. I answered it with the below code as I don't know of another way than using any Collections API or iterating over the Stack and using comparisons.  Any ideas?

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stack lifo = new Stack();
        lifo.push(new Integer(4));
        lifo.push(new Integer(1));
        lifo.push(new Integer(150));
        lifo.push(new Integer(40));
        lifo.push(new Integer(0));
        lifo.push(new Integer(60));
        lifo.push(new Integer(47));
        lifo.push(new Integer(104));

        if(!lifo.isEmpty()){
            Object max = Collections.max(lifo);
            System.out.println("max=" + max.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @StephenTG Nope, can't get arbitrary elements without popping the stack.

Comment: You could use recursion that imitates iteration though. Hacky, but would technically avoid the no iteration restriction

Comment: Crazy long shot, but how literally should we take "comparing elements"? Does comparing *an* element to an intermediate variable still count (i.e. iterate over the stack, keeping a local maximum and comparing each element to that maximum value)

Comment: Is this Question Java Specific,  or interviewer wnated to aks you something different?

Comment: I can't see a way to do this if the stack is just handed to you and you're not allowed to look at the contents. Maybe the answer is "define a new Stack subclass where you override the `push` operation to update an internally-stored max value, and then define `public int max(){ return this.maxValue; }`"?

Comment: I suggest that you first write, in English with pencil and paper, a description of the steps you need to solve the problem.

Comment: My solution uses only built in functions of stack and no iteration or recursion.

Comment: @LukeW. As long as my postulate holds that comparing a single element to a temporary variable does not constitute "comparing elements"

Comment: Can we use StackSort? http://xkcd.com/1185/ (mouseover image)

Comment: Are there any Big O guarantees you need to keep/make?

Comment: @HenryKeiter - I was thinking the same thing.  Often times the idea of these questions if to see how you think/problem solve - taking a step back and asking a question like this demonstrates that

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a constructive question and is generating mostly jokes and discussion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stack with find-min/find-max more efficient than O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134129/stack-with-find-min-find-max-more-efficient-than-on)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit:**

> without iterating over the Stack

does not actually prohibit *all* iteration. Rather, the question only prohibits doing the simple

```
for (Integer i : lifo)
```

Thus, this solution satisfies the question's limitations.

---

Just empty a copy of the stack. pop each of the elements from the copy, checking for max against an integer all the while.

```
Stack<Integer> lifoCopy = (Stack<Integer>) lifo.clone();
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

while (!lifoCopy.isEmpty())
{
    max = Math.max(lifoCopy.pop(), max);
}

System.out.println("max=" + max.toString());
```

This will work for you in O(n) time even if your interviewers decide to be more restrictive and not allow more built in functions (max, min, sort, etc.).

Additionally, if you need to have the original unharmed, but can't use clone, you can do so with an extra stack:

```
Stack<Integer> reverseLifo = new Stack<Integer>();
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

while (!lifo.isEmpty())
{
    int val = lifo.pop();

    max = Math.max(val, max);

    reverseLifo.push(val);
}

while (!reverseLifo.isEmpty())
{
    lifo.push(reverseLifo.pop());
}

System.out.println("max=" + max.toString());
```

Finally, this assumes that comparison against a temp variable is acceptable. If no comparison is allowed at all, then this solution in conjunction with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841908/2479481) will work.

Comment: Wouldn't that reverse the order of the stack?

Comment: @LukeW. `Stack<Integer> lifoCopy = lifo.clone();` won't compile.

Comment: @Nima fixed with cast.

Comment: How is this not "iterating over the stack"?

Comment: @BenJackson OP intended no `for (Integer i : lifo)`. This is not iterating over the stack so much as it is iterating until the stack is empty.

Answer (score 31):

By using `Collections.min()` instead:

```
if (!lifo.isEmpty()) {
  Integer max = Collections.min(lifo, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
      return o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
  });
  System.out.println("max=" + max.toString());
}
```

*Note that the custom `Comparator` flips the comparison so that `Collections.min()` will actually return the max.*

Comment: Yes, interesting design consideration.

Comment: I'm not confident that this is in the spirit of the challenge, but I love the implementation :D

Comment: @HenryKeiter You're probably right, but I couldn't pass up the opportunity to be a smart-ass!

Comment: If it weren't kind of an obnoxious question, I'd say this was an obnoxious answer... but in context, it's perfect.

Answer (score 11):

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack lifo = new Stack();
        lifo.push(new Integer(4));
        lifo.push(new Integer(1));
        lifo.push(new Integer(150));
        lifo.push(new Integer(40));
        lifo.push(new Integer(0));
        lifo.push(new Integer(60));
        lifo.push(new Integer(47));
        lifo.push(new Integer(104));

        System.out.println("max= 150"); // http://xkcd.com/221/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Not sure will this satisfy your question need, but this way use of `max()` and `iteration` could be avoided, anyhow `sort` does use `iteration` and `Comparable`  in background.

```
if (!lifo.isEmpty()) {
    Stack sc = (Stack) lifo.clone();
    Collections.sort(sc);
    System.out.println("max=" + sc.get(sc.size() - 1));
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is the answer

Comment: @lc. Not sure, but this way stack order can be preserved while satisfying the OPs need.

Comment: Sorry I was asked to not use the Collections.sort either

Comment: @Smit _Collections.sort()_ uses comparisons in the background as well.

Comment: @c12 your question should reflect this.

Comment: @Juvanis Thanks for heads up. let me update the answer. and @ c12 I agree with @ LukeW.

Answer (score 7):

This code:

```
public static Integer max(Stack stack) {
    if (stack.isEmpty()) {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    else {
        Integer last = (Integer)stack.pop();
        Integer next = max(stack);
        stack.push(last);
        if (last > next) {
            return last;
        }
        else {
            return next;
        }            
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Stack lifo = new Stack();
    lifo.push(new Integer(4));
    lifo.push(new Integer(1));
    lifo.push(new Integer(150));
    lifo.push(new Integer(40));
    lifo.push(new Integer(0));
    lifo.push(new Integer(60));
    lifo.push(new Integer(47));
    lifo.push(new Integer(104));

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(lifo.toArray()));
    System.out.println(max(lifo));
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(lifo.toArray()));
}
```

outputs:

```
[4, 1, 150, 40, 0, 60, 47, 104]
150
[4, 1, 150, 40, 0, 60, 47, 104]
```

It is a recursion on a given stack, finds the maximum element and doesn't change the stack order.

However iteration is different from recursion only if you [define it like that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration#Computing). Also, to find maximum you *must* compare  all the elements somehow - in whatever mathematical form, with relational or bitwise operators like Anirudh [showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841908/679982). IMHO, pretty vaguely defined task.

Comment: I concur on the vagueness of the question. Some terms need to be clearly defined in the context, for it to be solvable.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [bitwise operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772780/find-the-maximum-of-two-numbers-without-using-if-else-or-any-other-comparison-op) instead..

```
public int getMax(int a, int b) 
{
    int c = a - b;
    int k = (c >> 31) & 0x1;
    int max = a - k * c;
    return max;
}
```

Now you can do

```
int max=Integer.MIN_VALUE-1; 
while(!stack.empty())
{
    max=getMax(max,stack.pop());
}
```

Comment: works, but destroys the stack. +1 for the `getMax` function. If the stack needs to be maintained, you need to `clone()` or maintain another stack as I discuss in my answer.

Comment: @LukeW. you can evade two stacks with recursion. see my answer. I think that anirudh's comparison and my recursion forms the answer. Unless of course, by "maintaining the stack" you mean not to pop/push it's elements?

Comment: @linski True, but the extra stack solution that I provide is not iterative regardless of how you define recursion.

Comment: @LukeW. I disagree. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration#Computing), broader definition: "Iteration in computing is the repetition of a block of statements within a computer program." That cover's all the loops and recursion. That's why I think the task is vaguely defined.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in O(1) time and O(n) memory.
Modify the push and pop method (or by inheritance extend the standard stack with your own) to keep track of the current max in another stack.

When you push elements onto your stack, push max(currentElem, maxStack.peek()) onto maxStack
When you pop elements off the stack, pop the current max from your max stack as well.

This solution illustrates it well, so I won't expand more on it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3435998/1007845

Comment: I think this must be the correct answer.  Outlawing "iteration" sounds like code for O(1) way to get max, which can only be done with a special data structure, not a generic `java.util.Stack`

Answer (score 4):

Time to think outside of the box. Use the [Wolfram Alpha REST API](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/), and ask it to compute the *result* of:

```
"maximum of " + Arrays.deepToString(lifo.toArray())
```

It will [return 150](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum+of+%5b4%2C+1%2C+150%2C+40%2C+0%2C+60%2C+47%2C+104%5d).

Answer (score 2):

1 x  -Push the element x into the stack.

2    -Delete the element present at the top of the stack.

3    -Print the maximum element in the stack.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.text.*;
    import java.math.*;
    import java.util.regex.*;
    public class Solution {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            Stack <StackItem> st = new Stack <StackItem> ();
            int n = sc.nextInt();//number of choice
            int choice;
            int max = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
               choice = sc.nextInt();
               if (choice == 1) {//insert/push an item
                  int newInt = sc.nextInt();
                  if (!st.isEmpty()) {
                      max = st.peek().currentMax;
                  } else {
                      max = 0;
                  }
                  if (newInt > max) {
                        max = newInt;
                  }
                  StackItem item = new StackItem(newInt, max);
                  st.push(item);
                } else if (choice == 2) {//pop
                    if (!st.isEmpty()) st.pop();
                } else if (choice == 3) {//print the maximum item
                    System.out.println(st.peek().currentMax);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class StackItem {
        int val;
        int currentMax;
        StackItem(int val, int max) {
            this.val = val;
            this.currentMax = max;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Super, I like it

Answer (score 1):

When you push elements into the stack, update the max value

```
void main()
    int max = Integer.min
    lifo.push(1)
```

while

```
   void push(Integer value) {
       //push into stack
       //update max value
   }
```

Comment: Can this be assumed? I believe you are only given a stack of integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a `TreeSet` with:

```
int myMax = new TreeSet<Integer>(lifo).last();
```

Comment: Why are you declaring an explicit comparator here?

Comment: @arshajii OK then. I'll edit it when I actually have a moment. Feel free to do the edits if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Use Collections.sort with a Comparator that sorts in descending order and then peek the top element from the Stack.

Comment: I think OP wants to preserve the stack.

Comment: Perhaps the answer should at least allude to that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stack lifo = new Stack();
        lifo.push(new Integer(4));
        lifo.push(new Integer(1));
        lifo.push(new Integer(150));
        lifo.push(new Integer(40));
        lifo.push(new Integer(0));
        lifo.push(new Integer(60));
        lifo.push(new Integer(47));
        lifo.push(new Integer(104));

        Object lifoArray[] = lifo.toArray();
        Arrays.sort(lifoArray);
        System.out.println(lifoArray[lifoArray.length-1]);
    }
}
```

`Arrays.sort()` arranges in ascending order, so the last value in the sorted array will be the max value.

Answer (score 0):

Without iteration you can do a recursive call. If it's not homework it isn't logical to do so. Or alternatively you can do this without iteration & recursion.

However a quick n simple approach is here:

```
public class StackDemo {
    public static int max = 0; //set this to least, may be negative
    public static Stack lifo = new Stack();
    public static void main(String[] args){        
        pushToStack(new Integer(4));
        pushToStack(new Integer(1));

        if(!lifo.isEmpty()){
            Object max = Collections.max(lifo);
            System.out.println("max=" + max);
        }
    }
    void static int pushToStack(Integer value){
        lifo.push(value);
        if(max<value){
        max = value;
        }
        return max;
    }    

}
```

Comment: is this supposed to be recursive ?

Comment: no, its not. its just a non-iterative solution without using max();