# How to find the third largest number out of 4 inputs without using arrays and only using three comparators or comparisons

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, optimization

The code that I have written is as follows :

```
 /*
    Program to find the 3rd largest no from 4 nos without using arrays and
 only using 3 comparators or comparisons

     */
    package d;


    public class thirdlargest {
        public static void main(String args[]) {

           int a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,soln;
           soln= Math.min(Math.max(a,b),Math.max(c,d));
           System.out.println("Third largest=" +soln);        
        }
    }
    /*
    Output:
    Third largest=2
     */
```

But this only works for the used pattern of input if I change the pattern the output will be wrong. How can I fix this code with only using 3 comparators or comparisons strictly and we can use any programming language

Comment: Why did you tag this C++?

Comment: is this even possible? haha

Comment: @HardikPatel I've seen this question before, and that was my comment to the other question. I have yet to see an algorithm do this.

Comment: Oops, I didn't think it through. :(
I deleted my incorrect reply which was to do: `soln= Math.max(Math.min(a,b), Math.min(c,d));`

Comment: This was asked in a technical test round during placement by the recruiters

Comment: You should go to them if you get the job and ask them for the solution haha.

Comment: wasn't selected because i used more comparisons. 2 got selected using the above code

Comment: @Bajal, that does not work. Just test with a=5, b=4, c=3, d=2 and you will get 4 as a result.

Comment: so that means that the numbers are in order?

Comment: If they got selected using above code, then recruiter isn't too bright. Choosing people that give wrong answer over people who admit they don't know the answer or believe there is *no* answer. Guess they're getting what they deserve: Inferior people.

Answer (score 3):

IMO it is not possible to find third largest number out of 4 numbers using only three comparisons:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,soln;
        int maximum1 = Math.max(a,b);
        int maximum2 = Math.max(c,d);

        if(maximum1 < maximum2) {
            // either c or d and we need more comparisons
        }
        else {
            // either a or b and we need more comparisons
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** Actually we can find the largest number or smallest number using 3 comparisons but probably not the third largest etc.

Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on/32394237#32394237) for finding kth largest number in `O(n)` time.

Comment: if it was in order we can

Comment: @HardikPatel, That is not an assumption the OP gave

Comment: Yeah, finding *either* the largest *or* the smallest is easy enough, but you cannot find both, or the ones in the middle.

Comment: @Hardik: Well did OP mention that?

Comment: yea just saying if that was the case it is possible but its not in this case

Comment: @asimes: Someone has downvoted as it was +3 previously.

Comment: @akhil_mittal, You have enough rep to see that no one has downvoted. Click on the current number (2)

Comment: @JinuGeorge: What do you mean?

Comment: @asimes: Yea my bad. It seems someone upvoted then changed his mind later :)

Comment: @akhil_mittal Sorry I didn't read the comments in the if condition

Comment: @JinuGeorge: No problem :)

Comment: This kind of problem is known as [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) and the algorithm for solving it is known as [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm). The fastest known algorithm is [quick select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) which is expected to run in Theta(n).

Comment: There's an interesting [book](https://github.com/esbanarango/Competitive-Programming/blob/master/%C2%B7Documentation/Books/Introduction.to.Algorithms.3rd.Edition.Sep.2010.pdf) explaining the algorithm. It's in chapter 9

Comment: @Gerald: cormen is a classic text. No doubt about it :)

Comment: You can find the [maximum of two variable without using comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772780/find-the-maximum-of-two-numbers-without-using-if-else-or-any-other-comparison-op). Using only bit hack.

Comment: @invisal Thanks for the link. I used it to give answer using 3 comparisons.

Comment: @Andreas: You may need to take care of overflow as well.

Comment: @HardikPatel hahahah! If it was in order every search for the nth largest would be O(1).

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/lower-bound-for-finding-second-largest-element) on the Math StackExchange site discusses the problem of finding the 2nd largest of N values.  It states (with proof) that the lower (tight) bound is N + ceiling(log<sub>2</sub>N) - 2

For N == 4, that evaluates to 4.

(This applies here because the 3rd largest of 4 is also the 2nd smallest of 4.)

I don't think the proof excludes (hypothetical) solutions with less than 4 comparisons that rely on the N numbers being unique.  But that was not part of the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the exact definition of "comparator" is, the way they're using it.  But assuming that `Math.min` and `Math.max` don't count as comparators, here's a way to compute it using *no* comparisons or comparators:

```
public static int thirdLargest(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    int min = Math.min(a, Math.min(b, Math.min(c,d)));
    int offset = min + 1 - Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    a -= offset;
    b -= offset;
    c -= offset;
    d -= offset;
    min = Math.min(a, Math.min(b, Math.min(c,d)));
    return min + offset;
}
```

Computing the third largest number is the same as computing the second smallest number.  The trick in this code is that it computes the smallest number, then subtracts from each number the exact offset needed to make the smallest number wrap around and become Integer.MAX_VALUE, while not wrapping around for the other values.  The smallest of the remaining numbers is now the second smallest of the original numbers, minus the offset, which we'll add back.

However, I'll concede that this only works if all four numbers are distinct--or, at least, if the lowest two numbers are distinct.  It fails if you give it a=1, b=1, c=2, d=3--it outputs 2 instead of 1.  At least this should get you points for your problem-solving skill, which is what I assume the question is intended to find out.  It had better not be to find out how you would actually solve this in a production situation, because putting restrictions like this on production code (no arrays) would be lunacy.

**EDIT:**

Here's another solution.  There's one comparison in the code, but it's in a method that's executed three times, so that should count as three comparisons.

```
public static int thirdLargest(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    if (isThirdLargest(a, b, c, d)) {
        return a;
    }
    if (isThirdLargest(b, a, c, d)) {
        return b;
    }
    if (isThirdLargest(c, a, b, d)) {
        return c;
    }
    return d;
}

public static boolean isThirdLargest(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    int z = 3 + ((b - a) >> 31) + ((c - a) >> 31) + ((d - a) >> 31);
    // z = number of other parameters that are >= a.  Note that all of the
    // shift operations will return either 0 or -1.
    int y = 3 + ((a - b) >> 31) + ((a - c) >> 31) + ((a - d) >> 31);
    // y = number of other parameters that are <= a
    int x = -y >>> 31;
    // x = 1 if there are any other parameters <= a, 0 if not.  Note that
    // x can be 0 only if z == 3.
    int w = z & (x << 1);
    // This will be 2 if a is the third largest.  If z == 2, then x == 1
    // and w will be 2.  If z == 3, and x == 1, that means that a is the
    // smallest but is equal to at least one of the other parameters;
    // therefore a is also the third largest.  But if x == 0, a is
    // strictly smaller than all other parameters and is therefore not the
    // third largest.
    return w == 2;
}
```

*Note:* This may suffer from overflow problems, if there are two numbers that differ by 2<sup>31</sup> or greater.  Converting all the parameters to `long` should avoid the problem (also all the 31's would be changed to 63), but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I'm sure that Math.max and Math.min >>do<< count as comparisons.  So you have actually got 6 comparisons here.

Comment: If I were asked this question, I'd have to ask the recruiters what the exact definition is.  To me, a comparison is one of the 6 comparison infix operations.  If they want to define the term in a different way, they need to explain what the rules are.

Comment: And if they really decide that I can't use `max` and `min`, I'll fake them using the bit hack mentioned by invisal.  Of course, I'd have to know about it beforehand, or else I'd have to figure out on the fly which would be difficult.

Comment: Using the link provided by @invisal, `min()` can be implemented without using comparisons, so your answer is good in that aspect. I have provided alternate answer that handles duplicate numbers, using the allowed 3 comparisons, but for distinct inputs your answer is great, so up-vote from me.

Comment: Question: Isn't `min + 1 - Integer.MIN_VALUE` the same as `min - Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @invisal for link to algorithm to [find the maximum of two numbers without using comparison operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772780/find-the-maximum-of-two-numbers-without-using-if-else-or-any-other-comparison-op).

I flipped it to return minimum instead, then used as follows to find second lowest value, aka third highest:

```
private static int thirdHighest(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    int lowest = min(min(a,b),min(c,d));
    if (a == lowest)
        return min(min(b,c),d);
    if (b == lowest)
        return min(min(a,c),d);
    if (c == lowest)
        return min(min(a,b),d);
    return min(min(a,b),c);
}
private static int min(int a, int b) {
    return b - (((a - b) >> 31) & 0x1) * (b - a);
}
```

Exactly 3 `==` comparisons.

Works for input numbers in any order and also works if duplicate numbers are given.

*Note:* If inputs are constrained to be distinct, then the answer by @ajb can truly do it without any comparisons, by using the min/max bit manipulation of the link provided by @invisal.

Comment: You can also use xor instead of `==` and argue that you do not use comparisons at all. Your solution is cheating, I think.

Comment: @stgatilov I'm not so sure: you could say `if (a ^ lowest == 0)` but that still involves a comparison.  How do you propose to use `xor` without a comparison?  In any case, the term "comparison" was never strictly defined, so we can't tell whether we're breaking any rules or not.

Comment: Just write `if (a ^ lowest)` and be happy. Add `~` if needed. Well, perhaps that would not work in Java...

Comment: @stgatilov `a ^ lowest` is an `int` value, and `if (int)` is not valid in Java. It's valid in other languages, but not Java.

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted by @Andreas is very clean and readable. There is another solution that is less clean and less efficient. The solution relies on catching errors when dividing by zero. We keep on adding 1 to each number and then use the following expression to see if an error occurred:

```
1 / (currentNumber - Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

The second number that threw an error will be the third largest number out of the four. Even though the code has 4 comparison operators `=`. It will only run two of these statements: One for the first error, and one for the second error. For a total of two comparison statements. This method works for any set of input integers, both positive and negative.

```
public class thirdlargest 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        System.out.println("Third highest number: " + thirdHighest(1, 2, 3, 4));     
        System.out.println("Third highest number: " + thirdHighest(4, 3, 2, 1));  
        System.out.println("Third highest number: " + thirdHighest(-5, -4, -3, -2));  
        System.out.println("Third highest number: " + thirdHighest(0, 0, 0, 0));  
    }

    private static int thirdHighest(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        int testa = a, testb = b, testc = c, testd = d;

        int divisionResult;
        int numberFound = 0;

        while(true)
        {             
            try
            {
                divisionResult = 1 / (testa++ - Integer.MAX_VALUE); 
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                numberFound++;
                if(numberFound == 2)
                {
                    return a;
                }
            }

            try
            {
                divisionResult = 1 / (testb++ - Integer.MAX_VALUE); 
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                numberFound++;
                if(numberFound == 2)
                {     return b;
                }
            }

            try
            {
                divisionResult = 1 / (testc++ - Integer.MAX_VALUE); 
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                numberFound++;
                if(numberFound == 2)
                {
                    return c;
                }
            }

            try
            {
                divisionResult = 1 / (testd++ - Integer.MAX_VALUE); 
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                numberFound++;
                if(numberFound == 2)
                {
                    return d;
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TmaxFourNo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter no.'s:");
        int w = sc.nextInt();
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int y = sc.nextInt();
        int z = sc.nextInt();
        int m1 = Math.min(Math.max(w, x), Math.max(y, z));
        int m2 = Math.max(Math.min(w, x), Math.min(y, z));
        if (m1 < m2) {
            System.out.println("Tmax=" + m1);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Tmax=" + m2);
        }
        sc.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers.  It is best to provide an explanation of why your solution works and why it may be preferred to the other answers provided.

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer.