# A formula that returns the greater of two variables

Tags: math

This isn't specific to any particular programming language, although I happen to be working in JavaScript.

I am trying to create a mathematical formula that results in the higher of the two variables without using a comparison operator.

Example:
X = 10;
Y = 14;

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: In JavaScript you can use `Math.max()`, like this: `Math.max(X, Y)`.

Comment: What's your actual question about this?

Comment: Cross language dup: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4772780/2422776

Comment: It was a puzzle presented to me and I am trying to figure it out. It doesn't seem I have enough information to do this but I'm told it can be done.

Comment: @Azametzin Does it use comparison operators?

Comment: What are the rules of the puzzle? What counts as a comparison operator, and are you allowed to use built-in functions that do comparisons internally? What operations *are* allowed?

Answer (score 0):

For **positive** numbers or if you are only interested by **magnitude** (see comment below), you can use:

```
max(x,y)=(|x+y|+|x−y|)/2
```

You can also compute min with:

```
min(x,y)=(|x+y|-|x−y|)/2
```

Comment: Your solution says that the maximum of -1 and -3 is positive 3.

Comment: @kay3 opss, you are 100% right, this only works for positive numbers, thank you! I fixed my post